# How to get historical Google Earth imagery into R

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap, rgooglemaps

Using R, it is possible to query the Google maps API for the most current imagery from specified locations e.g.

```
library(ggmap)
mal <- get_map('Malabo', zoom = 12, maptype = 'satellite')
ggmap(mal)
```

Does the API allow/support queries for historical imagery from user specified dates?. If yes:

-how can this be done in R?

-If it can not be done in R, are there other ways/tools to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: What do the help pages at Google itself say?

Comment: Well, it advises that if stuck, one should post their issue/question on stackoverflow: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this? I am currently looking for a way to obtain imagery based on a specific year.

Comment: No, not yet. Still hoping :-)

Comment: still nothing on this?